# PHP DOMDocument - get html source of BODY

Tags: php, html, dom, parsing, domdocument

I'm using PHP's DOMDocument to parse and normalize user-submitted HTML using the `loadHTML` method to parse the content then getting a well-formed result via `saveHTML`:

```
$dom= new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<div><p>Hello World');
$well_formed= $dom->saveHTML(); 
echo($well_formed);
```

This does a beautiful job of parsing the fragment and adding the appropriate closing tags. The problem is that I'm also getting a bunch of tags I don't want such as `<!DOCTYPE>`, `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>`. I understand that every well-formed HTML document needs these tags, but the HTML fragment I'm normalizing is going to be inserted into an existing valid document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IN your case, you do not want to work with an HTML document, but with an HTML fragment -- a portion of HTML code ;; which means DOMDocument is not quite what you need.

Instead, I would rather use something like [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) *(quoting)* :

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant
>   HTML filter library written in  PHP.
>   HTML Purifier will not only remove all
>   malicious  code (better known as XSS)
>   with a thoroughly audited,  secure yet
>   permissive whitelist, it will also
>   **make sure your documents are  standards compliant**, something only
>   achievable with a  comprehensive
>   knowledge of W3C's specifications.

And, if you try your portion of code :

```
<div><p>Hello World
```

Using [the demo page of HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php), you get this clean HTML as an output :

```
<div><p>Hello World</p></div>
```

Much better, isn't it ? ;-)

*(Note that HTMLPurfier suppots a wide range of options, and that taking a look at its documentation might not hurt)*

Comment: There's good information here, but I'd argument that DOMDocument is still a legit tool for this.  The existence of a "loadHTML" method implies that DOMDocument is meant for parsing HTML documents as well as XML documents. HTMLPurifier or other "true" HTML parsers written in PHP are great, but their perf. is always going to pale when compared to built in PHP Objects.

Comment: @Alan : I agree that DOMDocument is great when it comes to parsing HTML Documents ;;; but for HTML portions, especially **user-submitted**, I believe HTMLPurifier is a better tool : it's been created exactly for the purpose of filtering user-submitted HTML -- including from a security point of view *(For instance, DOMDocument doesn't care about XSS, while HTMLPurifier does ;;; DOMDocument doesn't allow you to specify which tags/attributes should be allowed, while HTMLPUrifier does)*

Answer (score 28):

The quick solution to your problem is to use an xPath expression to grab the body.

```
$dom= new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<div><p>Hello World');      
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$body = $xpath->query('/html/body');
echo($dom->saveXml($body->item(0)));
```

A word of warning here.  Sometimes loadHTML will throw a warning when it encounters certainly poorly formed HTML documents.  If you're parsing those kind of HTML documents, you'll need to find a [better html parser](http://alanstorm.com/parsing_html_with_php) [self link warning].

Comment: this will return <body>[CONTENT]</body> ... how can you get just [CONTENT]?

Answer (score 1):

Faced with the same problem, I've created a wrapper around DOMDocument called SmartDOMDocument to overcome this and some other shortcomings (such as encoding problems).

You can find it here: http://beerpla.net/projects/smartdomdocument

Answer (score 0):

This was taken from another post and worked perfectly for my use:

```
$layout = preg_replace('~<(?:!DOCTYPE|/?(?:html|head|body))[^>]*>\s*~i', '', $layout);
```

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: `$dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement->lastChild);`**
*Where `$dom->documentElement->lastChild` is the `body`-node but could be every other available `DOMNode` of the document.*

---

**Actucally the `DOMDocument::saveHTML`-method itself is capable of doing what you want.**
It takes a `DOMNode`-object as the first argument to output a subset of the document.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<div><p>Hello World');
$well_formed= $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement->lastChild); 
echo($well_formed);
```

There are several ways of retrieving the `body`-node. Here are 2:

```
$bodyNode = $dom->documentElement->lastChild;
$bodyNode = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
```

###### From the PHP Manual

> `public DOMDocument::saveHTML(?DOMNode $node = null): string|false`
> Parameters
> node
> Optional parameter to output a subset of the document.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php