# DOMDocument changing characters

Tags: php, wordpress, domdocument

`aren't` becomes `arenâ€™t` and various other silliness.

Here's the code; this is working within WordPress to automate removal of an element from several hundred posts.

```
function removeImageFromPages() {
    $pages  = get_pages(array('exclude' => '802,6,4'));
    foreach($pages AS $page) {
       if($page->post_content == '') { continue; }      
       $doc     = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
       $post_content    = stripslashes($page->post_content);
       @$doc->loadHTML($post_content);
       $content = $doc->saveXML(); 
       echo($content); exit;
    }
}
```

**Originally** the post content I'm manipulating was stored in a custom CMS. The **initial** scrape was done with DOMDoc, without any encoding issues. However, there seems to be some kind of trouble the second time around. All headers on everything are set as UTF-8, but I'm not very experienced with encoding. The first time, it was a pure HTML scrape. Now, I'm dealing with values directly from the database. What am I missing? (And is DOMDoc even the right tool for this job?)

Update - I'm still having the problem, but have new information.

If I print/echo/var_dump the content directly from WordPress ($page->post_content), there is no issue. Once it goes through $doc->saveXML or $doc->saveHTML, the characters become confused. They don't become predictably confused, though.

```
$doc->loadHTML($page->post_content);
echo($doc->saveXML());
```

Yields `arenâ€™t`. However

```
$doc->loadHTML($page->post_content);
$ps = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
echo($ps->item(3)->nodeValue);
echo($doc->saveXML($ps->item(3)));
```

Yields `arenât` (in both echos).

Also, if I copy/paste a string from the document directly into the function, it works perfectly. It's only when dealing with values passed from WordPress.

Comment: Check that your database connection, and the table collation, are also utf-8. You have to have a pure UTF-8 pipeline throughout the system. If even a single stage anywhere is some other character set, you're going to get mangled text like this.

Comment: Everything associated with the DB that I can see (charset and collation) is utf-8.

Comment: The connection itself has to be utf-8 as well. Try a `set names 'utf-8'`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: I've learned something new! However, I ran through every variable on that page ('show variables like "[item]";') and everything came back utf-8. I've had this issue before, but always assumed it was an encoding issue with my IDE/FTP program rather than an issue with DOMDocument. This is the first time the data hasn't touched my localhost, though, so I know it's not IDE/FTP.

Answer (score 1):

Going through the comments on [the PHP documentation page for DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php), it appears that `loadHTML` does not respect the encoding you might have set on the `DOMDocument`.

Instead, it will read it from the `meta` tag in the HTML. With the original scraping, I presume you were dealing with complete pages including meta tags.

The `post_content` of a WordPress page, however, as far as I know, is only a document fragment, not a complete HTML page (or did you change that?). So now it can't figure out the encoding from the content and defaults to ISO 8859-1 and screws everything up. Not to mention it adds a doctype and `html`and `body` tags etc. around the fragment.

I'm not entirely sure if DOMDocument is the right tool here, but I'm not sure what the alternative are in your case (apart from [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), obviously).

What you can probably do, though, is wrap a simple HTML structure around the post content, including a meta tag to make sure it's UTF-8, before you pass it to `loadHTML()` and [then use XPath to save just the body of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345670/php-domdocument-get-html-source-of-body/2345782#2345782).

Comment: Thanks! I checked the encoding going in and coming out, but didn't think about how it was handling it in process. Ultimately I used regex ("so now I have 2 problems" as I've been told), but will remember to surround it in proper html the next time i need to do mass editing.