# Export particular element in DOMDocument to string

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I'm importing some arbitrary HTML into a `DOMDocument` using the `loadHTML()` function, eg.:

```
$html = '<p><a href="test.php">Test</a></p>';
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

I then want to change a few attributes/node values using `DOMDocument` methods which I can do no problem.

Once I've made these changes I'd like to export the HTML string (using `->saveHTML()`), *without* the `<html><body>...` tags that the `DOMDocument` automatically adds to the HTML.

I understand why these are added (to ensure a valid document), but how would I go about just getting my edited HTML back (essentially everything between the `<body>` tags)?

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345670/php-domdocument-get-html-source-of-body) and while it offers some solutions I would rather do this 'properly', i.e. without using a string replace on the `<body>` tags. Validity of the HTML is not an issue as it's run through an HTML purifier before hand.

Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT**

I'm aware of the `$node` parameter added to `saveHTML()` in PHP 5.3.6, unfortunately I'm stuck with 5.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the [source code](http://svn.beerpla.net/repos/public/PHP/SmartDOMDocument/trunk/SmartDOMDocument.class.php) of this will help - They're using a regex to strip out the unnecessary strings:

http://beerpla.net/projects/smartdomdocument-a-smarter-php-domdocument-class/

```
$content = preg_replace(array("/^\<\!DOCTYPE.*?<html><body>/si",
                                  "!</body></html>$!si"),
                            "",
                            $this->saveHTML());

return $content;
```

**saveHTMLExact()** - DOMDocument has an extremely badly designed "feature" where if the HTML code you are loading does not contain `<html>` and `<body>` tags, it adds them automatically (yup, there are no flags to turn this behavior off).

Thus, when you call $doc->saveHTML(), your newly saved content now has `<html><body>` and `DOCTYPE` in it. Not very handy when trying to work with code fragments (XML has a similar problem).

SmartDOMDocument contains a new function called saveHTMLExact() which does exactly what you would want – it saves HTML without adding that extra garbage that DOMDocument does.

Also, other questions have asked similar things:

[How to saveHTML of DOMDocument without HTML wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879946/domdocument-savehtml-without-html-wrapper)

Comment: I hadn't seen "DOMDocument saveHTML without HTML wrapper?" despite searching, one of the answers on there sorted it (using `loadXML()` and then `saveHTML()`). Many thanks for the pointer :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try using DOMDocument->saveXML()?

```
<?php
$html = '<p><a href="test.php">Test</a></p>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$domnodelist = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
$domnode = $domnodelist->item(0);
echo $doc->saveXML($domnode);
?>
```

It outputs `<p><a href="test.php">Test</a></p>`

Comment: Thanks but I won't necessarily know the type of the first tag in the body, it needs to be generic

Answer (score 0):

*Thanks but I won't necessarily know the type of the first tag in the body, it needs to be generic*

```
$domnodelist = $doc->getElementsByTagName('*');
$domnode = $domnodelist->item(0);
echo $doc->saveXML($domnode);
```