# how to access DOM in php that will echo out everything between <html></html>

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Export particular element in DOMDocument to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978822/export-particular-element-in-domdocument-to-string)

i know how to access different element depending on id but don't know how to get everything between html start tag to html end tag. Can anyone please help me. 
thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is your input and desired output? Do you simply want to serialize a DOMDocument to a string?

Comment: input would be for example, www.hello.php. this url. and that will return everything between <html></html> including tags like img, div, p

Comment: So you have an html string or url, and you want to return the children of `html` as a string, or as DOM objects, or something else?  (You realize it's possible to have valid html that doesn't have the `html` element?)

Comment: i know what you mean.  
i will give you an example what i am really after. here is the address of an accessibility checker site. valet.webthing.com/page....... if you just add www.drumstudio.ie... you will see it produce all the code that is written in the "drumstudio" page. i am trying to do the same thing as that. hope it makes it bit clearer. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to parse an html page with PHP, you could use PHP's DOMDocument extension, as such:

```
// a new dom object
$dom = new domDocument;
// load the html into the object
$dom->loadHTML($html);
// keep white space
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
// nicely format output
$dom ->formatOutput   = true;
//get element by tag name
$htmlRootElement = $dom->getElementsByTagName('html');
echo htmlspecialchars($dom->saveHTML(), ENT_QUOTES);
```

Or you could do this with JavaScript on the client side:

```
var htmlRootElement = document.getElementsByTagName("html");
alert(htmlRootElement.innerHTML);
```

Comment: i just tried your code there. I got everything in between tags. what i mean is if there is <h1>hello DOM</h1> then i got "hello DOM". but what if i want to get the whole line including the h1 tags. This will be true for everything all the divs, all the img tags. if you know what i mean. thanks

Comment: I see. Could you please try to replace the last line with this one echo DOMinnerHTML($htmlRootElement); . I have updated the answer. Or this one echo $dom->saveHTML();

Comment: i replaced this line, echo ($htmlRootElement->item(0)->nodeValue); with this line, echo DOMinnerHTML($htmlRootElement); its giving me an error. Call to undefined function DOMinnerHTML()

Comment: nope its giving me an error,  Call to undefined function DOMinnerHTML()

Comment: My bad, please try the other one instead - echo $dom->saveHTML();

Comment: i will give you an example what i am really after. here is the address of an accessibility checker site. http://valet.webthing.com/page/....... if you just add www.drumstudio.ie... you will see it produce all the code that is written in the "drumstudio" page. i am trying to do the same thing as that. hope it makes it bit clearer. thanks

Comment: Oh, ok. I have updated it again. Please try with this code.

Comment: thanks a lot mike. i got everything from the page but its all together. i mean one p tag is just after another not in the next line. if you know what i mean. any idea how to place them properly. and thanks again. that was brilliant. :)

Comment: Yes, just remove the line $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; . I have just updated the answer.

Comment: nope sorry did not do anything.

Comment: No, no, i meant now (updated the answer :-) ) $doc->formatOutput   = true;

Comment: nope nothing. still the same, this is what im trying............. $dom = new domDocument;
// load the html into the object
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.drumstudio.ie');
// keep white space
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
// nicely format output
$dom->formatOutput   = true;
//get element by tag name
$htmlRootElement = $dom->getElementsByTagName('html');
echo htmlspecialchars($dom->saveHTML(), ENT_QUOTES);

Comment: hi mike thanks for all your help, i have added one thing then it works the way i want it to be....................just added <pre></pre>              $dom = new domDocument;
// load the html into the object
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.drumstudio.ie');
// keep white space
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
// nicely format output
$dom->formatOutput   = true;
//get element by tag name
$htmlRootElement = $dom->getElementsByTagName('html');
$new = htmlspecialchars($dom->saveHTML(), ENT_QUOTES);
echo '<pre>' .$new. '</pre>';

Comment: Wow, great! I have been trying to figure it out and eventually gave up ... Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1):

You can access each element in the `<html>` tag with the DOMDocument class.

Example

```
$htmlDoc = new DOMDocument;

$html = <<<HTML
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Site</title>
    <meta name="description" content="DOM test">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>This is a DOM test</p>
</body>
</html>
HTML;

$htmlDoc->loadHTML($html);
$htmlElement = $htmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("html");

foreach ($htmlElement->item(0)->childNodes as $element) {
    echo 'Element name: ' . $element->nodeName . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Element value: '. $element->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: i tried something like this but getting error.                    Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array                                       $htmlDoc = new DOMDocument;  
$htmlDoc->loadHTML("http://www.drumstudio.ie/index.html");
$htmlElement = $htmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("html");
foreach ($htmlElement[0]->childNodes as $element) {
    echo 'Element name: ' . $element->nodeName . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Element value: '. $element->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}

Comment: Whoops, forgot to use `item()` method to access first element (There's only one). I know you've already accepted another answer but I thought I'd fix this one ;)