# grab text in the middle to a variable

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP DOMDocument - get html source of BODY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345670/php-domdocument-get-html-source-of-body)

I have the following code as a variable and trying to grab everything in between the body tags (while keeping the p tags etc). Whats the best way of doing this?

- pregmatch
- strpos / substr

  ```
  <head>
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <p>Services Calls2</p>
  </body>
  ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither. You can use a XML parser, like [`DomDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($var);

$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

$content = '';

foreach($body->childNodes as $child)
  $content .= $dom->saveXML($child);
```

Comment: This works well but i get &#13; added the the start and end of the new variable. how do i remove that also.

Comment: This will not be recursive throughout the <body>, it will only fetch the first level of tags. (not reason for -1 though, still the right way to go, just needs some more code :)

Comment: I think this is a quite slow way of getting a small data since DomDocument uses DOM Parser which reads the whole document first. "Represents an entire HTML or XML document;" From doc

Comment: @Lilleman: That's not true, contents of the tags are fetched as well

Comment: @user112570: that appears to be part of the new line character on Windows. Try normalizing new lines from the string before passing it to the parser, like `$var = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $var);`

Comment: +1 for introducing dom into it, I did something similar, created a different class for the same

Answer (score 1):

Try this, $html has the text:

```
$s = strpos($html, '<body>') + strlen('<body>');
$f = '</body>';

echo trim(substr($html, $s, strpos($html, $f) - $s));
```

Comment: It would be more reliable if you would use `strrpos('</body>')` to get the closing tag position

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use preg_match because contents between `<p>Services Calls2</p>` can change all the time then subtr or strpos is going to require quite controversial code.

Example:

```
$a = '<h2><p>Services Calls2</p></h2>';
preg_match("/<p>(?:\w|\s|\d)+<\/p>/", $a, $ar);
var_dump($ar);
```

The regex is going to allow alphabets, space and digits only.

Comment: I think preg_match is not a method of parsing